# RegExp replacing with value found in subject string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Using JavaScript, I'm replacing all occurrences of certain words with `<span>` tags containing that word. This is how I'm doing it right now:

```
regEx = new RegExp('\\b(?![^<>]*>)'+word+'\\b', 'gi');
context.innerHTML = context.innerHTML.replace(regEx, '<span class="reference">'+word+'</span>');
```

Which works well, but there's a problem: say I have `word = 'mass'`, and in the text I have `Mass`: since the search is case-insensitive, which it needs to be, it will match it, but it'll lose the capital `M`, wich is no good.
Is it possible for me to use the matched string from the regEx instead of the word string I'm looking for? I know it's possible to do in PHP with `preg_replace` using `$0` etc., but how would I do it in JS?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch the word using `()` then use `$1` to get it.
Read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/24th3sah(v=vs.94).aspx
Like this:

```
regEx = new RegExp('\\b(?![^<>]*>)('+word+')\\b', 'gi');
context.innerHTML = context.innerHTML.replace(regEx, '<span class="reference">$1</span>');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I thought the `$1` system was only in PHP!

Answer (score 2):

you should do something like this

```
regEx = new RegExp('\\b(?![^<>]*>)('+word+')\\b', 'gi');
context.innerHTML = context.innerHTML.replace(regEx, '<span class="reference">$1</span>');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As I already found y out from Issam, it should be $1

Answer (score 1):

It's much the same thing in JS.  Just add the parentheses for a capturing group:

```
var regEx = new RegExp('\\b(?![^<>]*>)('+word+')\\b', 'gi');
```

Then it works as you'd like (but note that `$0` is the whole string, so you want `$1`):

```
"a patriot from Boston, Mass was found...".replace(regEx, "<span class='reference'>$0</span>")
//=> "a patriot from Boston, <span class='reference'>Mass</span> was found..."

"difference between mass and weight is...".replace(regEx, "<span class='reference'>$1</span>")
//=> "difference between <span class='reference'>mass</span> and weight is..."
```

**[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** has probably the best reference.